# Python for line in file?

Tags: python, string, file, loops

Is there a way to create a loop in Python that reads a file, line by line, and does an action using the line? For example:

```
for eachLine in '~/file':
    print eachLine
```

which would print `~/file` to the terminal

Comment: have you tried `readline()` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were so close, all you had to do was [`open()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) the file:

```
with open(os.path.expanduser('~/file')) as inputfile:
    for eachLine in inputfile:
        print eachLine
```

By using a `with` context manager block, the file is automatically closed when you are done with the loop.

Comment: Aside: the OP might need to use `os.path.expanduser('~/file')`.

Comment: It has an extra newline, is there a way to get `print()` to skip the newline?

Comment: @tkbx: You really, really want to go read the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/)... In python 2, `print` is a statement, not a function. You can add a trailing comma to omit the newline and use a space instead: `print eachLine,`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm using `from __future__ import print_function`

Comment: @MartijnPieters another question yields `print('hello world', end='')`

Comment: @tkbx: But you didn't find the [`print()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print) documentation yet? `print(eachLine, end='')`.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to open the file in your loop:

```
for eachLine in open(os.path.expanduser('~/file')):
    print eachLine
```

On Win7 and OpenSUSE 12.1 (and I'm sure others) I've seen python doesn't like the "~" part of the path, so the `os.path.expanduser` fixes that.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is at : [click](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)

I did not write the some codes here, because at link there are many different ways for your question. Have fun.